# dllunregisterserver failed with error code 0x80070005

Tags: visual-studio

I compiled my C++ project under release mode in Visual Studio 2008. My development OS is Windows XP. The compilation works fine. But when I try to register the Dll using `regsvr32` on another machine, which is a Windows 7, this error appear:

```
dllunregisterserver failed with error code 0x80070005
```

Anyone call tell me what is wrong?

Comment: A handy tip:  Visual Studio comes with an `errlook.exe` utility which will give a brief translation of many error codes (including 0x80070005). Even better is the freely downloadable 'Exchange Server Error Code Lookup' utility (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=be596899-7bb8-4208-b7fc-09e02a13696c&displaylang=en), which is useful for far more than Exchange Server-related errors (they basically parse all the error codes from the Windows SDK headers into the utility).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you even try searching on the Internet first? A quick search brought up several results, such as [this one](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/trbl_nt_rgsvrfld80070005.htm):

> The error value ‘0x80070005’ means ‘Access Denied’.
>
> This means that an attempt has been made to update part of the registry that you do not have permissions to update.
>
> Check that you have local administration rights.

Comment: thanks guys! i right click on the command prompt icon, and select Run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your dll to be registered only at user level. 
change Per-user redirection to '**Yes**' then your dll will be able to registered for non admin users also.

Go To Project Properties->Linker->Genral->Per-user redirection. to **Yes**